# How to set type of a class using local variable that holds that type?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I've got a method that does the following:

```
 val type = AClass::class.java.methods[0].parameters[0].type
 val toDeserialise = SecondClass<type>()
```

My SecondClass is:

```
class SecondClass<T : Any> {
    lateinit var p1: T
}
```

But this doesn't work. Basically, I want to take a type of a method's parameter and pass it into a SecondClass. Do you know how to implement this?

The AClass is:

```
class AClass{
   fun myMethod(param1: String, param2: UUID)
}
```

So, I want the

```
val type
```

to be String, which I pass into SecondClass.

Comment: Post relevant parts of `AClass` you're trying to reflect.

Comment: @Pawel I've added AClass to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is resolved at runtime, and generic types are resolved at compile time.

The `SecondClass` is subject to [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure), so what you want to do is essentially impossible.

Even if you try to work around it with a switch:

```
val type = AClass::class.java.methods[0].parameters[0].type
val toDeserialize = when(type){
    String::class.java -> SecondClass<String>()
    else -> SecondClass<Any>()
}
```

This will bring you no benefit since you won't be able to check the actual type of `SecondClass`.